# How can I supply a mixed element to a component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
<GuideTable
  description={['Query parameters for ', <code>/oauth/authorize</code>, ' in the authorization code grant']} />
```

How can I better clean this code up so I don't need to escape `<code>/oauth/authorize</code>` within a mixed array?

I've tried escaping it with the ``` {``} ``` syntax, but supplying the description prop as `` {`Query parameters for ${<code>/oauth/authorize</code>} in the authorization code grant`} `` just gets rendered out as "Query parameters for [object Object] in the authorization code grant".

Any ideas?

Comment: So what do you want to output exactly ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I want the code element within the sentence to be rendered out as a code element.

Comment: Ok, so how are you rendering the `description` property inside `GuideTable` ?

Comment: `{this.props.description}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
const GuideTable = (props) => {
    return (<div>
        {props.description}
        <div>My other stuff in Guide Table</div>
    </div>);
};
<GuideTable description={<>Query parameters for <code>/oauth/authorize</code> in the authorization code grant</>}/>
```

This passes in a fragment for the description.

Comment: Oh fascinating, I had no idea about fragments. We're still on 15.6.*, but have been meaning to upgrade for a bit now. This will work great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this the result you were looking for?

```js
const App = () => (
  <GuideTable
    description={['Query parameters for ', <code>/oauth/authorize</code>, ' in the authorization code grant']}
  />
);

const GuideTable = ({description}) => (
  description.map((item, i) => <React.Fragment key={i}>{item}</React.Fragment>)
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

This will render two text nodes to the DOM, and a `<code>` element. No escaping needed.

Comment: I'm looking more for a solution where I don't have to supply a mixed array as the `description` prop. We have a lot of these in our codebase, and it's a maintainability headache right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) property, which is the react replacement for `innerHTML`.

```js
const App = () => (
  <GuideTable
    description='Query parameters for <code>/oauth/authorize</code>, in the authorization code grant' />
);

const GuideTable = ({description}) => (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:description}}></div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```